# Why is Dictionary.ContainsKey returning False when the key is an int[]?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reference-type, containskey

I'm working on some map generation, but I have run into an issue. Below is the simplified code. It returns False whilst it should return True.

```
static Dictionary<int[], Tile> map = new Dictionary<int[], Tile>();

static bool GenerateMap()
{
    

    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            Tile tile;
            int[] i = {x, y};
            if(map.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                
                tile = map[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Contains!");
            
            }
            else
            {   
                tile = new Tile();
                tile.Generate();
                map.Add(i, tile);                
            }
       
        }
    }
    int[] z = {0,0};
    if (map.ContainsKey(z)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

I have tried Dictionary.TryGetValue() and Try / Catch, but neither worked.

Comment: Arrays are reference objects which means that unless they override `Equals` the default `Object.Equals` will be used which considers two objects equal only if they are actually the same object. Two arrays containing the number 2 aren't equal to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

> ```cs
> static Dictionary<int[], Tile> map = new Dictionary<int[], Tile>();
> ```

Make the dictionary key a [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1) or a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) instead of an `int[]`:

```cs
static Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, Tile> map = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, Tile>();
```

or

```cs
static Dictionary<(int x, int y), Tile> map = new Dictionary<(int x, int y), Tile>();
```

Then use it throughout your code.

[KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1)s and [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)s are [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types#:%7E:text=C%23%20provides%20the%20following%20built-in%20value%20types%2C%20also,4%20char%20that%20represents%20a%20Unicode%20UTF-16%20character). You can check these for equality in the usual ways. `ContainsKey` will work as expected.

An [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) in C#. By default, no 2 arrays will ever be equal to each other, unless they are the same object.